# Error segment in swift (EXC_BAD_ACCESS)

Tags: ios, swift

When run app return nothing and show 
`Thread1:EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address 0x…)`

The code is in Swift 2, the image below shows the code and the error:

[image]

Where do you think that is the problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot assign items to UISegmentedControl, you have to initialize it with the items by calling it's designated initializer:

```
let segment = UISegmentedControl(items: ["one", "two", "three"])
```

You can also set the items from storyboard which I think is the approach you should go for because it seems you created the UISegmentedControl from storyboard and established a connection to the segmentListDetail IBOutlet property in your view controller.

Comment: I don't use directly from UISegmentedControl

Comment: I don't understand what you said, can you rephrase that statement?

Comment: I found solution :) tanks